# Arbitrary Stateful Operations in Spark on different type of column using same state

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have json which as column name as key and row as the value.
A value could be a string or numeric datatype.
As per my use case, I am using arbitrary stateful operation, to compute the following operation
For Numeric datatype: I have a calculating min, max and sum.
For String datatype: I am calculation valid or invalid string.

To extract out value type from JSON I parse the value as below

```
 val jValue = parse(value)

              jValue match {
                case JObject(l) ⇒
                  l foreach { case (colName, colData) =>
                    colData match {
                      case JDouble(value) => // numeric stats computation
                      case JString(value) => //  string stats computation
                        }}}
```

For this, I am using Arbitrary Stateful operations

```
           dataFrame
          .select(col("key").cast("string").as("key"), col("value").cast("string").as("value"))
          .as[(String, String)]
          .groupByKey { case (key, _) => key }
          .mapGroupsWithState(mapFunc)
```

I just to know how can I maintain my state for both type of datatype ???
So that when I get numeric value, I have only numeric statistics and same is for string datatype.